# Blazor security understanding

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am a newbie with Blazor and i do not really understand what is runned on browser and what is runned on server.

I have read some C# code is translated into javascript, but what i have understood is that each javascript event is send to server via a websocket. Am i wrong ?

Here is a short example: Do you think this code is secure :

```
<p>@message</p>

<input type="text" @bind-value="@login"/>
<input type="password" @bind-value="@password"/>

<button @onclick="@on_btn_login_click">Connexion</button>

@code 
{
    private string message = "";
    private String login = "";
    private String password = "";

    private async void on_btn_login_click()
    {
        if (login == "hello" && password == "world")
        {
            message = "Welcome !";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Wrong login/pass";
        }
    }
}
```

Or may somebody see the good login/pass in his browser source code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this in Blazor Server-side then the on_btn_login_click() is stored and executed on the Server so yes, this code is relatively secure.

When you use this in Blazor Client-side (Blazor WebAssembly) then the on_btn_login_click() is served to the Client as IL code and it is quite easy for any hacker to extract your secrets.